# PHP - preg_match explanation

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Im a beginner in PHP I just want to ask can someone explain to me this line of code.

```
(preg_match('/^\w{5,}$/', $username))
```

Thankyou in advance. :) Your answer is so much appreciated. :)

Comment: How about reading the documentation?  http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-match.php

Comment: actually. I've tried reading many topics about preg_match but still its hard for me to understand. the ('/^) in the code says that it was a start of the pattern and ($/') is the ending of it. now i struggle in \w{5,} I cant understand this. can you help me? :(

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html#special http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PHP match string is

> /^\w{5,}$/

and a PHP match string is surrounded by `/` characters which are not part of the RegEx string itself.
According to the comments your problem is about understanding regular expressions, not PHP.

> ^  is the beginning of the line, correct
>
> $  is the end of the line, correct
>
> \w Any word character (letter, number, underscore)
>
> a{5,} does mean 5 or more characters 'a'

Therefore: If there are 5 or more any word characters in the username the function returns a positive result.

Or even easier: A username needs to contain at least five any word characters.

Learn more about regular expressions and how they work. Some explanation [can be found in this comment](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-match.php#105924).

Comment: wow! now i understand thanks man. :) This gives hope. XD thankyousomuch. :)

Comment: stricly speaking `^` matches the start of a line and `$` matches the end of a line

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: Thank you for the help guys. Much appreciated. :) Now I understand how to use it. :) btw i cant post any more question. i would like to ask what is wrong in this code

<?php
function user_exists($username) {
 $username = sanitize($username);
 $query = @mysqli_query("SELECT COUNT(`UserID`) FROM users WHERE `Username` = '$username'");
 return (@mysqli_result($query, 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}
?>

it keeps printing that the account do not exist eventhough it is. Im using xampp version 7 and i think that @mysql_result is the problem can you help me please. :3

Comment: Im cringing right now because this is my project for web based subject in our school. and tomorrow is my defense im still stuck at this. :(